# Невозможно вставить явное значение для столбца идентификаторов в таблице Customers, Areas, Projects когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-core

Пишу учебный проект. Возникла данная проблема - обшарил все сайты и форумы, сравнил свою БД с БД одногруппника, но так и не могу понять, что не так и как решить.
Использую EF Core 8.0.2 и WPF MVVM.

Есть площадь, в которую нужно добавить точки (координаты площади), но при нажатии на кнопку добавления вылетает Exeption сразу с тремя таблицами.
Уже пробовал SET IDENTITY_INSERT <имя таблицы> ON, [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] и пересоздавать БД, но ничего не помогает.

Код моделей:

```
public class Customer : PropChange {
    private int id;
    public int Id {
        get => id;
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id)); }
    }

    private string? name;
    public string? Name {
        get => name;
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name)); }
    }

    private string email;
    public string Email {
        get => email;
        set { email = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Email)); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Project> projects;
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects {
        get => projects;
        set { projects = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Projects)); }
    }
}
```

```
public class Project : PropChange {
    private int id;
    public int Id {
        get => id;
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id)); }
    }

    private string? name;
    public string Name {
        get => name;
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name)); }
    }

    private string? address;
    public string? Address {
        get => address;
        set { address = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Address)); }
    }

    private Customer customer;
    public Customer Customer {
        get => customer;
        set { customer = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Customer)); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Area> areas;
    public ObservableCollection<Area> Areas {
        get => areas;
        set { areas = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Areas)); }
    }
}
```

```
public class Area : PropChange {
    private int id;
    public int Id {
        get => id;
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id)); }
    }

    private string? name;
    public string? Name {
        get => name;
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name)); }
    }

    private Project project;
    public Project Project {
        get => project;
        set { project = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Project)); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<AreaCoords> coords;
    public ObservableCollection<AreaCoords> Coords {
        get => coords;
        set { coords = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Coords)); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Profile> profiles;
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> Profiles {
        get => profiles;
        set { profiles = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Profiles)); }
    }
}
```

Код AreaVM:

```
void AddCoord(object obj) {
    var coord = new AreaCoords();
    db.AreaCoords.Add(coord);
    db.SaveChanges(); <-- Exeption!
    SelectedCoord = coord;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Area));
}
```

Класс контекста:

```
public class AggContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AreaCoords> AreaCoords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProfileCoords> ProfileCoords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Picket> Pickets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Measuring> Measurings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer($@"Server=.;Database=AggAppNew;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;");
        //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=AgeenkovAppNew;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```